# Unable to forward the query parameters submitted by the user

Tags: python, node.js, apache, http, webserver

I want to forward a request entered in the browser like:

```
example.com/?wid=23&lang=en
```

to a server running on a different port like:

```
http://localhost:3001/?wid=23&lang=en
```

How could I do this?

I have added a VirtualHost in the apache, like below:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But I do not know how to pass the query parameters to a Nodejs application running on a different port.

Comment: In your VirtualHost configuration, shouldn't you be redirecting the requests to port `3000` instead of `3001`?

Comment: @Zeeshan Typo..